# What is the name of this about 5cm high, grey, Beanie shaped fungus?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found those below some stone stairs in Germany. The grass gives you an impression of the size (I guess the grass is about 5-7cm tall)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is *[Coprinellus disseminatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinellus_disseminatus)*, also known as "Fairy Inkcap". Size (they are pretty small) and also the color fits pretty well. See the image from the Wikipedia:

[image]

Some more information can be found [here](http://www.first-nature.com/fungi/coprinellus-disseminatus.php).